# Can legendary effects trigger on different classes?

Tags: diablo-iii

[Vigilance](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/vigilance) has a chance on being hit to cast Inner Sanctuary, which is a Monk skill. Could this effect trigger if I'm not playing a Monk? What about other legendary items with seemingly class-specific effects?

Some weapons with class skills:

- [Skywarden](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/skywarden)
- [Blade of Prophecy](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/blade-of-prophecy)
- [Wizardspike](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wizardspike)
- [Odyn Son](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/odyn-son)

Comment: Chain Lightning is not a class skill, btw. And yes, it works.

Comment: If you are a monk, does the skill cast by the weapon take into account the runes you have equipped to the skill?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find an authoritative source, but if it doesn't say "Monk Only" then it will work.  It will cast a non-runed version of that spell.

Comment: that's correct, if it doesn't say class only it works.  However if you are the correct class it won't say that on the legendary.  It'll only say <class only> if you are the wrong class.